# How to get the edited cell position in Angular material table

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-table

I get this table in angular material

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
 <ng-container matColumnDef="{{this.columnsToDisplay[3]}}">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{this.columnsToDisplay[3]}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index">
      <mat-form-field class="form-input">
        <input type="number" matInput [(ngModel)]="quincenaUrl==1?element.dia2:element.dia17"
          (keyup.enter)="editarCelda($event)" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

....
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky:true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" class="element-row"></tr>
  <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No se han encontrado coincidencias</td>
  </tr>

</mat-table>
```

When I edit a value and Press Enter in my class I get the event

```
editarCelda(event: any) {
 console.log("Nuevo Valor", event.target.value);
}
```

And I know how to get the value but I don't know how to get the row and column edited, that is, the position of the edited cell

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the row and column when calling the editarCelda method

```html
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{this.columnsToDisplay[3]}}">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      {{this.columnsToDisplay[3]}}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index">
      <mat-form-field class="form-input">
        <input
          type="number"
          matInput
          [(ngModel)]="quincenaUrl==1?element.dia2:element.dia17"
          (keyup.enter)="editarCelda($event, i, this.columnsToDisplay[3])"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  ....
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay; sticky:true"></tr>
  <tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
    class="element-row"
  ></tr>
  <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No se han encontrado coincidencias</td>
  </tr>
</mat-table>
```

```js
editarCelda(event, row, col) {
  ...
}
```